# WPF textboxes and touch keyboard

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, windows-10, touch

I am trying to build a WPF application that needs to work on Windows 10 tablet having touch screen. So Windows touch keyboard must pop up as user taps a TextBox and go away as he taps something else.

Current version of .NET framework (4.7) and Windows 10 (16299.192) seem to offer this functionality out of the box so we don't need to bother starting/killing TabTip.exe any more, but... There is a very annoying bug which ruins everything and I can't figure out how to work it around.

To demonstrate the issue I built a simple WPF app having one window like that:

```
<Window x:Class="TextboxTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="Height" FontSize="40" Width="400">
  <StackPanel Margin="20">
    <TextBox Margin="5" Padding="10"/>
    <TextBox Margin="5" Padding="10"/>
    <Button Margin="5" Padding="10" Content="Ruin it!"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When I start the app, the top TextBox gets focused, touch keyboard pops up (assuming Windows is in Tablet mode). I can type immediately, this works fine. Then I tap another TextBox, keyboard stays on screen, tap the first TextBox again - everything is just fine up to this point.

But as soon as I tap the button (also checked with other focusable controls like InkCanvas) - keyboard goes nuts. So when I tap the button it disappears, this is fine. But when I tap a TextBox after that it flashes for a fraction of a second and immediately closes. I tap the same TextBox again - keyboard pops up. I tap another TextBox - it closes. I have to tap each TextBox twice after that. This is extremely annoying. I can't find any way to exit this broken state except for relaunching the application.

The behavior looks like a bug in WPF for me. It looks like some usage counter gets off or something.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did u find a resolution to this as I am experiencing the same issue?